# Laravel 5.5. sharing sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session, token, csrf

I have CSRF token issues when communicating in this manner

```
subdomain --> domain
```

I have set the `session.php` to have a value

```
"domain" => "." . env('APP_URL'),
```

and when I inspect cookies, they do have a value of `.example.com`.

Even with this, I am getting a `TokenMissmatchException` when trying to forward a login `POST` request.

Can this be done, or do with this approach only subdomains communicate, but not the main domain?

Comment: are two servers using same session driver and sessions store at the same location?

Comment: It is all one Laravel application. No multiple servers, so they are sharing `session.php`

Comment: what session driver are you using?

Comment: File. blahblah need to write blah

Comment: Did the session files save without problem at the location `storage/framework/sessions`? And did you include X-CSRF-TOKEN header or _token params for csrf checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that in `Kernel.php` I had

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
```

listed twice. Both under global middleware and web middleware which is now included in all Laravel routes by default. It was doing a double encryption, thus making this discrepancy.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

It won’t matter if the keys are the same, the csrf_token has to be expected.

Make sure you’re sending the [CSRF token with the request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

Comment: I am sending them, but I get different tokens in session and the one forwarded in request